# CORS error with S3 even after adding CORS configuration

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors

I am trying to upload images to an S3 bucket via javaScript. When submitting the request, the following error returns:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://somebucket.s3-us-west 
2.amazonaws.com/albums//apicture.png. Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://someorigin:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My CORS configuration on the bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://someorigin:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I even manually added the origin to the policy as you can see, along with `*`, but nothing seems to be working, and I'm not sure where to begin.

I examined the network pane in the Chrome Devtools and noticed that one of the XHR was `apicture.png`, and it had the following key information:

```
Request URL:https://somebucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/pics/apicture.png
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
```

The `response` tab had some other important information:

```
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>
<Bucket>somebucket</Bucket>
<Endpoint>somebucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<RequestId>
***************
</RequestId>
</Error>
```

So, it is clear that they want the region to be `us-west-1` however, if I change my `AWS.config` to that, throws a different error. Amazon's own guides say that the area "Northern California" are encoded as `us-west-2`, so I am not sure why there is this inconsistency.

Comment: `Response to preflight` - looks like it's the preflight that fails - what http method are you using (GET, POST, etc) and what request headers - check the developer tools network tab to see the network traffic details of your request

Comment: @JaromandaX POST, and under 'request Headers' there are many. Any in particular you are thinking of?

Comment: no, just non standard ones do trigger a preflight - which clearly is the point of failure according to the message - not familiar with amazon-s3 so I can't really help, except to point out it's the preflight (i.e. the OPTIONS call) that fails

Comment: Which region is the bucket actually in? N. California is us-west-1, not us-west-2 (which is Oregon).

Comment: The bucket is in N. California. If I change the code to us-west-1, it says "OPTIONS https://cognito-identity.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", probably becuase the identity pool Id is in us-west-2, but I cannot change that, so I'm really lost.

Comment: Longshot, but did you ever resolve this Marc?

Answer (score 3):

Now you need to set in JSON.
Permissions -> CORS

```
[{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 Bucket =>  Add MetaData 'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'

Comment: How does this help the question Ajay Tiwari, does cache control addresses the cors error in anyway?